# Algorithm for the Hill cipher (finding the inverse of the determinant of a $2 \times 2$ matrix modulo $26$)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I have a good understanding of how to do the [Hill cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher) on paper but putting 
it into program form is somewhat of a problem.

Finding the the determinant is 
the thing I'm having problem with. On paper if the matrix is 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 8 \\ 11 & 11 \end{pmatrix},$$
then you multiply $7 \times 11$ and $8 \times 11$ then
subtract the $77 - 88$ which is $-11$ then add $-11$ to $26$ and you get $15$ and 
after that you do the $15 x \equiv 1 \pmod{26}$.
It says the easiest way to do this is trial and error multiplying $15$ by $1$ though $9$ and you find that $15\cdot7$ is $105$ and 
divide $105$ by $26$ you get $1$ and the determinant is $7$.

This works on paper but 
writing a program to do this what would be a good way to do this. Is there a 
a different way to find the determinant or maybe doing the matrix a different 
way to give the determinant.

Comment: If you compute the GCD of two numbers $p, q$ using [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) and keep tracks of the terms during each step. At the end, you will find two numbers $m, n$ such that $\gcd(p,q) = m p + n q$. In the special case when $p, q$ are relative prime, the $n \equiv q^{-1} \pmod p$. Look at the wiki page of [extended Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described will work very well on a computer even with numbers having several dozens of digits (at some point, you will just have to replace the exhaustive search for the modular inverse with the extended Euclidean algorithm).

The benefits of using sophisticated number-theoretic algorithms only start to kick in for very large numbers (say, a hundred of digits or more), except for hard problems like factoring.